# How to switch conda env to use with jupyter notebook (win10)

Tags: python, windows, conda

I am trying to work with the package RDkit, I installed it with conda fallowing the documentation command:

```
conda create -c rdkit -n my-rdkit-env rdkit
activate my-rdkit-env
```

the prompt is telling me it is using the new env, I then launch jupyter notebook from this prompt but I can't import rdkit, it seems to be using the regular env. Also for some reason python is not recognize in cmd nor powershell after installing conda (anaconda is in PATH)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `conda install jupyter` from the terminal in your new environment before launching a new jupyter notebook.

I had this same problem with Spyder, a code editor which would launch in Python2 when launched from a Python3 environment, unless I installed Spyder in that specific Python3 environment first.